# Python-Fanuc read Parameter Variable pyfanuc

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to read data from a cnc fanuc with pyfanuc (https://github.com/diohpix/pyfanuc) library in python.

I'm able to read pmc variable, macro variable but i'm trying to read the parts count of a 0i fanuc Parameter No. 6711 (from the 0i fanuc pdf
https://www.fryermachine.com/pdf/support/programming/fanuc0i/Fanuc%20Series%200i%20MODEL%20F%20Plus%20Parameter%20Manual_B-64700EN_01.pdf
pag 390).

```
from pyfanuc.pyfanuc import pyfanuc


conn=pyfanuc('192.168.8.223')
if conn.connect():
    #read pmc
    n=conn.readpmc(1,9,3712,1)
    print(n)

    #read macro
    n=conn.readmacro(9723)
    print(n)

    #read param
    n=conn.readparam(conn.ALLAXIS, 6711,0)
    print(n)

    #console print
    #461
    #0.0
    #None
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

check your code on pyfanuc.py. you will see parameter last will set default 0
and if last = 0 function will set last = first.

```
def readparam(self,axis,first,last=0):
    if last==0:last=first
```

So you will try to input 6711 to first and 6712 to last.
I use this condition on FANUC controller 18i-PB that work.
Function will return to dictionary form and separate data with parameter.
But this repository not updated for 2 years. There have some bugs that I mention to fix for example in function 'statinfo', if you don't use controller 16 and 31 version, this function cannot execute. you just add more cnctype

```
if (self.sysinfo["cnctype"]==b"16" or self.sysinfo["cnctype"]==b"31" or self.sysinfo["cnctype"]==b"18")and st["len"]==0xe:
```